# How to convert json value database to html

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have notification table on my database where the value is using like json.

Here's my table

```
id |     touserid      |            data                 
  1         2                 a:1:{i:0;s:10:"INV-000001";}                    
  2         2                 a:1:{i:0;s:10:"INV-000003";}                  
  3         2                 a:1:{i:0;s:15:"The Mej Hotel";}                    
  4         1             a:5:{i:0;s:28:"Total Goalsi:1;s:7:"6250000";}           
  5         1                 a:1:{i:0;s:10:"INV-000007";}
```

I want to use that value in html table, but I don't know how to convert the value to html table in codeigniter

Here's my view code

```
<table class="table table-dark">
                      <tbody>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Data</th>
                            <
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <?php foreach($notifications as $notif){ ?>
                          <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $notif['id'] ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $notif['data'] ?></td>
                          </tr>
                          <?php } ?>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Here's controller code

```
$this->db->limit($this->misc_model->get_notifications_limit(), $offset);
    $this->db->where('touserid', get_staff_user_id());
    $this->db->order_by('date', 'desc');
    $data['notifications'] = $this->db->get(db_prefix() . 'notifications')->result_array();

    $this->load->view('admin/sales/sales', $data);
```

But I don't see the data value get into html table like I want, in table it's show the error message " not_goal_message_failedArray"

I'm trying to encode the json, but I still don't know how to pass the json encode in controller to view in codeigniter

Here's the json encode

```
$page   = $this->input->post('page');
        $offset = ($page * $this->misc_model->get_notifications_limit());
        $this->db->limit($this->misc_model->get_notifications_limit(), $offset);
        $this->db->where('touserid', get_staff_user_id());
        $this->db->order_by('date', 'desc');
        $notifications = $this->db->get(db_prefix() . 'notifications')->result_array();
        $i             = 0;
        foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
            if (($notification['fromcompany'] == null && $notification['fromuserid'] != 0) || ($notification['fromcompany'] == null && $notification['fromclientid'] != 0)) {
                if ($notification['fromuserid'] != 0) {
                    $notifications[$i]['profile_image'] = '<a href="' . admin_url('staff/profile/' . $notification['fromuserid']) . '">' . staff_profile_image($notification['fromuserid'], [
                    'staff-profile-image-small',
                    'img-circle',
                    'pull-left',
                ]) . '</a>';
                } else {
                    $notifications[$i]['profile_image'] = '<a href="' . admin_url('clients/client/' . $notification['fromclientid']) . '">
                <img class="client-profile-image-small img-circle pull-left" src="' . contact_profile_image_url($notification['fromclientid']) . '"></a>';
                }
            } else {
                $notifications[$i]['profile_image'] = '';
                $notifications[$i]['full_name']     = '';
            }
            $data = '';
            if (!empty($notification['data'])) {
                $data = unserialize($notification['data']);
                $x               = 0;
                foreach ($data as $dt) {
                    if (strpos($dt, '<lang>') !== false) {
                        $lang = get_string_between($dt, '<lang>', '</lang>');
                        $temp = _l($lang);
                        if (strpos($temp, 'project_status_') !== false) {
                            $status = get_project_status_by_id(strafter($temp, 'project_status_'));
                            $temp   = $status['name'];
                        }
                        $dt[$x] = $temp;
                    }
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            $notifications[$i]['description'] = _l($notification['description'], $dt);
            $notifications[$i]['date']        = time_ago($notification['date']);
            $notifications[$i]['full_date']   = $notification['date'];
            $i++;
        } 
        echo json_encode($notifications);
```

Do you know where's my error when tried convert the json value in the table to html table code ?

Thank you

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON; it looks like a [serialized array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

Comment: your error message is not clear please make it clear and can you explain more about your issue with table design?

Comment: Hi @M.Hemant, in the table I don't see the value that I want, but I got the error message " not_goal_message_failedArray"  in the table

Comment: Hi @showdev, thank you, but when I tried json_encode, it's showing data but in json format

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Are you encoding the serialized string as JSON? It might help to include the part of the code where you do the encoding/decoding.

Comment: Hi @showdev, I have included encoding part in my question

Comment: Thank you. It seems that you fetch `$notifications` from the database and then loop through that array. What is the purpose of encoding the data as JSON? What I mean is: why not just loop through the array without encoding it as JSON?

Comment: I've tried before, but it's not working, however when I'm trying using json encode, it's show the data

Answer (score 0):

1. Your data in your table is looking like a serialised array
2. You will not get the data via echo, should use

   $this->load->view("notification_view", $notifications);

instead of

```
echo json_encode($notifications);
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried code in view, but it's still not working, it's show nothing in the table